# Adding three numbers using CLIPS

Tags: clips, expert-system

I am a new to expert systems world.I am learning to use CLIPS tools.can anyone help me to make a program to add three numbers?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate add
   (multislot numbers))
CLIPS> 
(defrule add-3-numbers
   (add (numbers ?n1 ?n2 ?n3))
   =>
   (printout t ?n1 " + " ?n2 " + " ?n3 " = " (+ ?n1 ?n2 ?n3) crlf))
CLIPS> (assert (add (numbers 1 2 3)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (assert (add (numbers 2 9 11)))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (run)
2 + 9 + 11 = 22
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
CLIPS>
```

Updated:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(defrule add-3-numbers
   =>
   (printout t "Number 1? ")
   (bind ?n1 (read))
   (printout t "Number 2? ")
   (bind ?n2 (read))
   (printout t "Number 3? ")
   (bind ?n3 (read))
   (printout t ?n1 " + " ?n2 " + " ?n3 " = " (+ ?n1 ?n2 ?n3) crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Number 1? 1
Number 2? 2
Number 3? 3
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
CLIPS> (evenp 3)
FALSE
CLIPS> (oddp 7)
TRUE
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot please can you help me to write a program to determine whether a number is even or odd?

Comment: but how can i make your example used to get  any three inputs from the user and return the sum of them ?